# Mechano wheels instead of cylinders?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I'd like to insert "mechano wheels" (or other "cool' wheels) in my model instead of simple cylinders.
What do you suggest me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23730/mechano-wheels-instead-of-cylinders?/) by [Tobi92](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7359/tobi92/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I haven't follow this [tutorial](http://www.theconstructsim.com/robot-modeling-create-a-virtual-model-of-an-omni-wheel-robot-ep-1/) myself but it seems exactly what you need.

And there is another example of [model with "cool wheels"](https://github.com/GuiRitter/OpenBase).

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tobi92](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7359/tobi92/) on 2019-09-09**:
Thank you!